# Filtering multilevel dataframe by the values of the lower level

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three levels, let's call them Class -> Group -> Value:

```
Class   Group   Value   Fail
A       1       0       False
A       1       1       True
A       2       0       False
A       2       1       True
A       2       2       True
A       3       2       True
A       3       5       True
B       4       2       False
B       4       7       True
B       4       8       True
B       4       12      True
B       4       15      True
B       5       1       False
B       5       2       False
B       5       3       True
B       6       7       False
B       6       8       False
```

I need to get the groups where the minimal value in a group is equal to the minimal value in a class where `Fail==True`:

```
Class   Group   Value   Fail
A       1       0       False
A       1       1       True
A       2       0       False
A       2       1       True
A       2       2       True
B       5       1       False
B       5       2       False
B       5       3       True
```

So in the class A the minimal value with `Fail==True` is 1, and it is in the groups 1 and 2. in the class B the minimal value with `Fail==True` is 3 in the group 5.

How to do this?

Comment: Could you explain how this output matches the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation), once on Class and once on Group, get the `min` of Value. You want where both are equal `eq`

```
df[df['Value'].where(df['Fail']).groupby(df['Class']).transform('min')
     .eq(df['Value'].where(df['Fail']).groupby(df['Group']).transform('min'))]
   Class  Group  Value   Fail
0      A      1      0  False
1      A      1      1   True
2      A      2      0  False
3      A      2      1  False
4      A      2      2   True
12     B      5      1  False
13     B      5      2  False
14     B      5      3   True
```

if you have the same Group name in several Class, you should consider using the second `groupby` on both Class and Group.

```
df[df['Value'].where(df['Fail']).groupby(df['Class']).transform('min')
     .eq(df['Value'].where(df['Fail']).groupby([df['Class'], df['Group']]).transform('min'))]
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I need, although the output is right, but I need to take in mind the column `Fail` and get the minimal value having `Fail==True`

Answer (score 1):

We do it by two steps, find the `min` , find the id with the `min`

```
df1 =df[df.Fail].copy()
s=df1.groupby('Class').Value.min()
df=df[df.Group.isin(df1.loc[df1.Value.isin(s),'Group'])]
   Class  Group  Value   Fail
0      A      1      0  False
1      A      1      1   True
2      A      2      0  False
3      A      2      1   True
4      A      2      2   True
12     B      5      1  False
13     B      5      2  False
14     B      5      3   True
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to keep in mind the column `Fail` like it is in edited question.

Comment: @MichaelO. filter it :-)